# VB.net How To Validate Cells DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hey I got confused of what happen to my datagridview.

So I currently working with Purchases Form.

I make user input data directly to the table. The problems are the validation. At first try, I swear, I got it worked.

It checked all my cells, columns one by one. Stated the error messages as well for name, price, etc.etc. that they are empty. And so then the next rows.

But now, when I have input the ID and fill up name, I always got an error that "ID is empty".

Is it because the system directly check and move to the next rows and skipped the rest?

Anyone can help?

Ah when I tried to change the row variable on function cekInput(), with all 0
dgv.Item(0, 0).Value, dgv.Item(1, 0).Value, etc.etc

it's working, but only for one rows. I want system to check the next rows

```
Function cekInput() As Byte
    Dim row = dgv.RowCount - 1
    If dgv.Item(0, row).Value Is Nothing Then
        cekInput = 1
    ElseIf dgv.Item(1, row).Value Is Nothing Then
        cekInput = 2
    ElseIf dgv.Item(2, row).Value Is Nothing Then
        cekInput = 3
    ElseIf dgv.Item(3, row).Value Is Nothing Then
        cekInput = 4
    ElseIf dgv.Item(5, row).Value Is Nothing Then
        cekInput = 5
    Else
        cekInput = 0
    End If
End Function
```

And I don't have problems with database.. It's just that why the system skipped my validation?

```
Sub InsertPurchases()
    Dim cek As Byte = cekInput()
    Select Case cek
        Case 0
            Try
                Dim sql = "INSERT INTO pembelian (no_pmb,tgl_pmb,nm_supplier) VALUES ('" & NoPmb.Text & "','" & Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") & "','');"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                For i = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 2
                    sql = "INSERT INTO detail_pmb (no_pmb,id_brg,nm_brg,harga_brg,qty_disc,total,qty_brg,sub_total) VALUES ('" & _
                      NoPmb.Text & "','" & dgv.Item(0, i).Value & "','" & dgv.Item(1, i).Value & "','" & dgv.Item(2, i).Value & "','" & dgv.Item(3, i).Value & "','" & dgv.Item(4, i).Value & "','" & dgv.Item(5, i).Value & "','" & dgv.Item(6, i).Value & "');"
                    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
                MsgBox("Data Pembelian Berhasil Dicatat", vbInformation, "Pesan")
                clr()
                dgv.Rows.Clear()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Data Pembelian Gagal Dicatat", vbCritical, "Error")
            Finally
                'conn.Close()
                AutoNoNota()
            End Try
            InactvItem(True)
        Case 1
            MsgBox("Kode Barang Harus Di-Isi", vbCritical, "Pesan")
        Case 2
            MsgBox("Nama Barang Harus Di-Isi", vbCritical, "Pesan")
        Case 3
            MsgBox("Harga Barang Harus Di-Isi", vbCritical, "Pesan")
        Case 4
            MsgBox("Jumlah Disc Harus Di-Isi", vbCritical, "Pesan")
        Case 5
            MsgBox("Jumlah Barang Harus Di-Isi", vbCritical, "Pesan")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the `DataGridView` `dgv` have a `DataSource`? Maybe a `DataTable`?

Comment: opps.. maybe not.. Don't know where to put it either